# Failed to initialize pocketsphinx keyword spotting on Windows

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am attempting to get a speech recognition engine running in python using keyword detection by PocketSphinx. I installed it through pip and managed to find some code for keyword detection in an answer to another question. The code I'm using is below:

http://pastebin.com/Qd7i19jM

For some reason, I keep getting this error, does anybody know why?

```
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 83: Folder '/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model\hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k' does not contain acoustic model definition 'mdef'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Christian/PycharmProjects/speech/buffer.py", line 12, in <module>
    decoder = Decoder(config)
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\pocketsphinx.py", line 277, in __init__
    this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok Windows, the model path should be different, something like `C:\Users\Christian\Downloads\pocketsphinx\model`, you need to point to the actual path where model files reside. You can copy model files yourself to some folder and point that folder to application.